# file.delete() wont delete file, java

Tags: java, file-io

Okay, this is going to be a bit long. So I made a junit test class to test my program. I wanted to test if a method that uses a Scanner to read a file into the program threw and exception, if the file didn't exist like this:

```
@Test
public void testLoadAsTextFileNotFound()
{
    File fileToDelete = new File("StoredWebPage.txt");  

    if(fileToDelete.delete()==false) {
        System.out.println("testLoadAsTextFileNotFound - failed");
        fail("Could not delete file");
    }

    try{    
        assertTrue(tester.loadAsText() == 1);
        System.out.println("testLoadAsTextFileNotFound - passed");
    } catch(AssertionError e) {
        System.out.println("testLoadAsTextFileNotFound - failed");
        fail("Did not catch Exception");

    }
}
```

But the test fails at "could not delete file", so I did some searching. The path is correct, I have permissions to the file because the program made it in the first place. So the only other option would be, that a stream to or from the file is still running. So I checked the method, and the other method that uses the file, and as far as I can, both streams are closed inside the methods.

```
protected String storedSite; //an instance variable
/**
* Store the instance variable as text in a file
*/
public void storeAsText()
{
    PrintStream fileOut = null;
    try{
        File file = new File("StoredWebPage.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        fileOut = new PrintStream("StoredWebPage.txt");
        fileOut.print(storedSite);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        if(e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        fileOut.close();
    } finally {
        if(fileOut != null)
            fileOut.close();
    }
}

/**
* Loads the file into the program
*/
public int loadAsText()
{
    storedSite = ""; //cleansing storedSite before new webpage is stored
    Scanner fileLoader = null;
    try {
        fileLoader = new Scanner(new File("StoredWebPage.txt"));
        String inputLine;
        while((inputLine = fileLoader.nextLine()) != null)
            storedSite = storedSite+inputLine;
        fileLoader.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        if(e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            return 1;
        }
        System.out.println("an Exception was caught");
        fileLoader.close();
    } finally {
        if(fileLoader!=null)
            fileLoader.close();
    }

    return 0; //return value is for testing purposes only
}
```

I'm out of ideas. Why can't I delete my file?

EDIT: i've edited the code, but still this give me the same problem :S

Comment: Maybe not exactly your problem, but are you sure, that no other exception than FileNotFoundException occurs in your code? For example problems while closing your streams etc. Because catching all exceptions and handling only FileNotFoundException throws all other exceptions away without letting you know, that any problem happened.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Windows won't let you delete any file that's open by any process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here. The first is that if an exception is thrown during your write to the file, the output stream is not closed (same for the read):

```
try {
    OutputStream someOutput = /* a new stream */;

    /* write */

    someOutput.close();
```

The second problem is that if there's an exception you aren't notified:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        /* do something */
    }

    /* else eat it */
}
```

So the problem is almost certainly that some other exception is being thrown and you don't know about it.

The 'correct' idiom to close a stream is the following:

```
OutputStream someOutput = null;
try {
    someOutput = /* a new stream */;

    /* write */

} catch (Exception e) {
    /* and do something with ALL exceptions */

} finally {
    if (someOutput != null) someOutput.close();
}
```

Or in Java 7 you can use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: And always print and/or log the stack trace.

Comment: I edited the code, but still this didn't solve the problem edit: i forgot to print something for all other exceptions on storeastext, and that was the problem. It threw another exception

Comment: What is the exception? Print the stack trace with `e.printStackTrace();` like @chrylis suggests. Also remember you don't have to close in the catch block. That is what the finally block is for.